# Output MSIL in separate file

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, cil

How to output the generated MSIL code in a separate file? I know there was an compiler option, because I used it (I think in VS2012) for a short time, but I cannot find this option anymore, I cannot even find this option in the [compiler options list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6ds95cz0.aspx).

Comment: Hard to guess what "file" you might be talking about.  I'd guess at /target:module

Comment: Almost. But I mean that the compiler outputs the compiled assembly in human readable MSIL (I think the file format is .il). I could attach an example of what format the compiler should output.

Comment: That's produced by ildasm.exe, the C# compiler could never do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way you can create an IL file of your assemblies is to add Post-build events that will execute when the build is successful.

In VS, you can do this by going to opening *Project properties* screen, and going to the `Build Events` tab.

From there, just set a Post-build event, similar to the one below.  Please note, I had to add the reference path of the ildasm.exe application to my Windows PATH environment variable.  If you have to do the same, this will require a log out and back in, for it to work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :)  At least a faster possibility than doing this on command line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, RLH.. i used full path... "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\ildasm.exe" MySimpleClassLibrary1.dll  /out=MySimpleClassLibrary1.il